# Default parameter for :make if $* is empty?

Tags: makeprg

Is it possible to provide a default if `$*` is empty in a `:make`?

I'd like to specify `:makeprg` so that:

1. `:make` runs `swift build`
2. `:make foo bar` runs `swift foo bar`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a vim answer, but consider having an actual makefile (or a shell script, but makefiles are beautiful for this kind of thing—see [the language agnostic makefile](https://blog.mindlessness.life/makefile/2019/11/17/the-language-agnostic-all-purpose-incredible-makefile.html?utm_medium=email&utm_source=topic+optin&utm_campaign=awareness&utm_content=20191123+prog+nl&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWm1FNVlUQTJNV0ZtTWpjMyIsInQiOiJjTTBaNmI5Y0hTeUlKdmdlelR4MUhER0dQUFFvdkFDc2R5eUJPQVVxUW1lcTRyVFlCVlwvcXg0aEdDNkV2OWRtdzQ0eERweFhIZnRGdml4VmNXY0VRTjd4TTNQbE9NQ1B2eHJjU0EzdVhwVUhMdnNvSWhtT2h0RnpGSDB0RURDaU0ifQ%3D%3D) and [is it worth using make](http://anadoxin.org/blog/is-it-worth-using-make.html?utm_medium=email&utm_source=topic+optin&utm_campaign=awareness&utm_content=20191123+prog+nl&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWm1FNVlUQTJNV0ZtTWpjMyIsInQiOiJjTTBaNmI5Y0hTeUlKdmdlelR4MUhER0dQUFFvdkFDc2R5eUJPQVVxUW1lcTRyVFlCVlwvcXg0aEdDNkV2OWRtdzQ0eERweFhIZnRGdml4VmNXY0VRTjd4TTNQbE9NQ1B2eHJjU0EzdVhwVUhMdnNvSWhtT2h0RnpGSDB0RURDaU0ifQ%3D%3D)).

Then, you don't need weird workarounds for vim's `$*` (I had to look it up to be sure of what you were talking about).

For example (pay attention to the tabs, which are showing as spaces, unfortunately):

```
all: build_output

build_output:
    swift build

foo_output:
    swift foo

bar_output:
    swift bar
```

Then you can simply `make`, `make foo_output`, or `make bar_output`, where
`*_output` is a file or directory tree generated by `swift *`.

Let make do its job. Don't beat it to death.

The equivalent shell script would have to be something like

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

usage() {
  cat <<DOG
usage: $0 [args...]
DOG
}

die() {
  local ex="${1:-1}"
  exit "$ex"
}

usage_and_die() { usage && die; }

build() {
  swift build
}

foo() {
  swift foo
}

bar() {
  swift bar
}

main() {
  if (($# < 1)) ; then
    build
  else
    for param;
      case "$param" in
        -h|--help) usage_and_die ;;
        *) "$param" ;;
      esac
    done
  fi
}

main "$@"
```

And the complexity of this beast will only grow. Just use make.

### Vim?

I suppose you could do something like

```
command -nargs=* Make if len(<q-args>) > 0 | make <q-args> | else | make build | endif
setlocal makeprg=swift
```

But then you have to use this new command, and maintain it, and all that garbage. Plus, if you have a workflow, why not encode that in your makefile, and let others benefit from seeing it?

Comment: I don't want a Makefile because Swift projects (with the Swift Package Manager) already have standards for building: `swift build`, `swift test`, etc. I want something that works for _all_ projects. My default for SwiftPM projects is to run build, but I should be able to run the tests too.

Comment: You must not have read the articles I linked. The point of the makefile is to standardize those commands for interacting with that project. It’s agnostic. But again, see the part at the end re: vim @mdiep